# How to create hive table on many .gz compressed .json files?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hdfs, gzip

I have directory on hdfs with .json files, .gz compressed ( almost 1k of them). I want to create hive table using those files (Cloudera environment). I tried many ways, for example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_data_table`(
    `timestamp` timestamp,
    `ip` string,
    `name` string,
    `id` string,
    `job` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
   'hdfs://my/files/location'
```

But table shows cell values as well as tags. (example:

> "name":"John"

instead of

> John

)  Data in .json looks like below (1 line of many, just for example):

```
{"timestamp":"2015-05-09T04:24:58Z","ip":"123.321.12.123","name":"John","id":"EX291236","job":"Programmer","phone":["number:2874723467","model:Alcatel","os:Android"]}
```

I was also wondering how to include "phone" data which needs to be handled some special way, obviously. Hope you guys can help me with that.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: Yes. In fact, this JSON file I've been provided with by data source, was some kind of their own interpretation of JSON (double quotes was not used properly in nested JSON structures). I was forced to use SQL build-in regexp replaces and splits, to parse this data so it was shown properly in final table.